# Which plugin to choose in cordova for geolocation using OpenLayers3?

Tags: openlayers, mobile, cordova

I built a mobile app using the OpenLayers 3 api and now I want to build it with cordova to install a apk package on a phone.

Should I install a plugin? (cordova plugin add plugin-name)

Which plugin should I install?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I don't need to install any additional plugins with cordova. Using the OpenLayers 3 API works when installing the app with the apk package.

Turns out that I just needed to allow "Geolocation" for my app in the android device (Settings -> Apps -> "MyApp" -> Permissions)